# setting animation back to idle not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have a door in my scene and when the player opens the door it plays an animation which is "open door"
Both on the door and the player itself.
after the animation is played the player no longer goes back to the "idle" animation and is just frozen on the first frame of the open door animation.

i have tried a couple things to fix it but it just either loops the animation forever or glitches out.

I am new to coding and i am not sure how i would continue my code on the player to put it back on idle.
here is the door script, i got it to find the player animator if set correctly in unity but even after trying to get it back to idle with a transition and a new tag it still didn't work? so i ctrl z'd and asking here how would i continue this?

```
using UnityEngine;
 
public class DoorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;
    public Animator playerAnimator;
 
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Player entered trigger");
        }
    }
 
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Player left trigger");
        }
    }
 
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && animator != null && animator.isActiveAndEnabled)
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("OpenDoor");
 
            if (playerAnimator != null && playerAnimator.isActiveAndEnabled)
            {
                playerAnimator.SetTrigger("OpenDoor");
            }
        }
    }
 
   
}
```

I tried setting a new trigger to when the door was opened to set the player back to idle in the animator but that didn't work, it just looped my character animation or very fast was switching between open door and idle animation.

Comment: Are you triggering from "Any State" in the animator controller? If you are, it should play the animation, and then return to "Entry" which should in turn pass onto your first animation (usually people put idle here).

Comment: There are many ways to continue your code. But it would be dependent on your needs. A simple way to call another animation at the end of one is to add an event to your animation clip, and on the event call a function that sets you back to the idle state. Check out the docs on animation events here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html

Comment: Also, there are ways to check what animation is currently playing, and if it is finished yet or not. You could check the animation, and if the door animation has finished, then call your next animation. Here is an answer to how you would get this working: https://answers.unity.com/questions/362629/how-can-i-check-if-an-animation-is-being-played-or.html   ----- Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: thank you all for the amazing answers. I have tried to make the code check when the animation stops playing to put it back to idle but that also glitched it out and i also tried to set an event to the animation to reset it but didn't get it working, could be that i did it wrong so i will try that next!